# How to test SQLAlchemy versioning in unit tests - Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, optimistic-locking

Note: Using flask_sqlalchemy here

I'm working on adding versioning to multiple services on the same DB. To make sure it works, I'm adding unit tests that confirm I get an error (for this case my error should be StaleDataError). For other services in other languages, I pulled the same object twice from the DB, updated one instance, saved it, updated the other instance, then tried to save that as well.

However, because SQLAlchemy adds a fake-cache layer between the DB and the service, when I update the first object it automatically updates the other object I hold in memory. Does anyone have a way around this? I created a second session (that solution had worked in other languages) but SQLAlchemy knows not to hold the same object in two sessions.

I was able to manually test it by putting time.sleep() halfway through the test and manually changing data in the DB, but I'd like a way to test this using just the unit code.

Example code:

```py
def test_optimistic_locking(self):
        c = Customer(formal_name='John', id=1)
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.flush()
        cust = Customer.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
        db.session.expire(cust)
        same_cust = Customer.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
        db.session.expire(same_cust)
        same_cust.formal_name = 'Tim'
        db.session.add(same_cust)
        db.session.flush()
        db.session.expire(same_cust)
        cust.formal_name = 'Jon'
        db.session.add(cust)
        with self.assertRaises(StaleDataError): db.session.flush()
        db.session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is possible, you need to create two separate sessions. See [the unit test of SQLAlchemy itself](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/test/orm/test_versioning.py#L200) for inspiration. Here's a code snippet of one of our unit tests written with pytest:

```
def test_article__versioning(connection, db_session: Session):
    article = ProductSheetFactory(title="Old Title", version=1)
    db_session.refresh(article)
    assert article.version == 1

    db_session2 = Session(bind=connection)
    article2 = db_session2.query(ProductSheet).get(article.id)
    assert article2.version == 1

    article.title = "New Title"
    article.version += 1
    db_session.commit()
    assert article.version == 2

    with pytest.raises(sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError):
        article2.title = "Yet another title"
        assert article2.version == 1
        article2.version += 1
        db_session2.commit()
```

Hope that helps. Note that we use `"version_id_generator": False` in the model, that's why we increment the version ourselves. See [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/versioning.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this question, my current hypothesis is that it can't be done. SQLAlchemy is incredibly powerful and, given that the functionality is so good that we can't test this line, we should trust that it works as expected